# is there a way to share a link on facebook messenger using facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using facebook SDK for iOS and actually to share link on facebook messenger but can not find sufficient help, I am able to share the image by downloading the image and then attaching the downloaded image but it takes too much time to first download image and then attach. Now all I want is to share a simple link to facebook messenger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you can use where there is no need to download image, you can set the image Url it will be downloaded on facebook App once shared

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *shareContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
[shareContent setContentTitle:@"Title"];
[shareContent setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someImageUrl]];
[shareContent setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURl]];

FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
messageDialog.delegate = self;
[messageDialog setShareContent:shareContent];

if ([messageDialog canShow]) {
    [messageDialog show];
} else {
    // Messenger isn't installed. Redirect the person to the App Store.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kFacebookMessengerAppiTunesUrl]];
}
```